# Reversing Checksum of serial protocol

Tags: deobfuscation, decryption, cryptanalysis

I'm trying to reverse engineer a serial protocol of a compressor, but i've no luck calculation the checksum.

e.g. here are some messages including the 16-bit checksum at the end of the message.

```
ff 02 ff 01 10 00 10 00 41 9e e2
ff 02 ff 01 10 00 10 00 42 9d e3
02 fe 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 fd c1
00 fe 02 83 01 10 00 00 00 00 6c c1
```

By now i know following octets

```
00  target addr
fe  seems like a seperator
02  own addr
83  register addr
01  value1 high
10  value1 low
00  value2 high
00  value2 low
00  value3 high
00  value3 low
6c  Checksum
c1  Checksum
```

I've tried to calculate the Checksum with different 16-Bit CRC's and brute-forcing with "reveng", but sadly i had no luck.

Also there is no way to put own Bits into the checksum function, but i can provide additional messages.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why not reverse engineer the code that produces the checksum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first byte is a simple checksum variant.  In C:

```
uint8_t firstbyte( uint8_t const *data, size_t bytes )
{
    uint8_t sum;
    for (sum = 0; bytes; --bytes)
        sum -= *data++;
    return sum;
}
```

The second byte is a shift and add thing something like the BSD checksum:

```
uint8_t secondbyte( uint8_t const *data, size_t bytes )
{
    uint8_t sum;
    for (sum = 0; bytes; --bytes) {
        sum = (sum << 1) | ((sum & 0x80) ? 1 : 0);
        sum += *data++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```